# How do I achieve a background screen color transition?

Tags: java, android, colors, android-framelayout

I have a game where I want the background's screen color to transition from one color to another every 10 points. Here is a method I created to try it:

```
private void backgroundColorswitch(Rectangle rect) {
    int color = mainView.getSolidColor(); /*I am trying to get the mainView's color for the transition's start color*/
    int red =   (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
    int green = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int blue =  (color >> 0) & 0xFF;
    int alpha = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
    colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(mainView, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue), rect.getColor() - 1000000); /*I want the transition to end on a faded version of the color of the rectangles that also change every 10 points*/
    colorFade.setDuration(2000); //length of transition
    mainView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            colorFade.start(); //Runs the animation
        }
    });
}
```

The every 10 points part is taken care of but I want to know if there is a better way to go about this. How would I get the FrameLayout's color because the color the color change ends on is correct but when I use `mainView.getSolidColor()` to get the Layout's current color the transition starts on a grayish white color and not the current color of the Layout.

Any solutions or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `FrameLayout` background is a solid color (and it should be in your case) then you can get it's color using the following code

```
Drawable background = mainView.getBackground();
int color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
```